# Laravel / eloquent and highmaps - data format

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following php / eloquent code in a controller:

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $subsByCtryArr = Organisation::join('countries_currencies', 'countries_currencies.id', '=', 'organisations.country_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT LCASE(countries_currencies.country_code) AS ctry, COUNT(organisations.id) AS regs'))
        ->groupBy('ctry')
        ->get();
    $subsByCtry = $subsByCtryArr->pluck('regs', 'ctry')->toJson();

    return view("sim-manager.dashboard", compact('subsByCtry', 'userByCtry'));
}
```

In my `blade`, inside a `JS` segment of code I put:

```
var subsCtry = {!! json_encode($subsByCtry) !!};
```

If log `subsCtry` to the console I get:

```
{"at":1,"au":10,"br":1,"nz":1}
```

But I need an array of objects for the `Highmaps`:

```
[['at', 1],['au', 10],['br', 1],['nz', 10]]
```

How do I format the data from the back end to my `JS` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing `json_encode` PHP function in my JS variable setting/

```
var subsByCtry = {!! $subsByCtry !!};
```